# NGINX forward Proxy config on windows machine for MSSQL - 1433

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

```
I am trying to update the config for proxy on Nginx

Scenario: Need to consume AWS-hosted MSSQL via Proxy

I have created a Virtual Machine(Windows) with Nginx installed. Under config updated the section for MSSQL -1433
```

On making request form my local box getting error as server was not found, but i am able to ping the public ip. And even ports are open.

```
I tried all options, updating config- always getting error as server not found. I am new to Nginx. and the VM is windows. Not sure if I am doing a config error.

**#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;
#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;
#pid        logs/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
stream {
    upstream dbtcp {
        server database.test.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:1433;
    }
    upstream dbudp {
        server database.test.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:1434;
    }
    server {
        listen 1433;
        proxy_pass dbtcp;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1s; # detect failure quickly
    }
    server {
        listen 1434 udp;
        proxy_pass dbudp;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1s; # detect failure quickly
    }
}
```

Even i added the stream section under http block

Comment: I ran the command to check if VM is listening on the port  by command netstat -a . That even looks fine, but not sure what changes required

Answer (score 0):

The connectivity was failing due to a firewall rule. Opened the port for 1433 and was able to connect